# Trying to use UISearchResult in Swift. How to implement filtering?

Tags: swift, search, filtering, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to create a campsite search feature in my app. I would like the user to be able to type into a search bar and have the displayed list of campgrounds filter to match what they are typing. Right now a user taps on a button to bring up SearchCampgroundsViewController.swift. Here is the code I have so far in that file:

```
import UIKit

class SearchCampgroundsViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var campgrounds: [Campground]? {
       return DataProvider.sharedInstance.allCampground()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension SearchCampgroundsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.campgrounds?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("campgroundCell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = campgrounds?[indexPath.row].facilityName ?? "NO NAME FOR THIS FACILITY"
        return cell
    }
}
```

The list of campgrounds is displaying correctly in the table view (the list is about 4000 items long), and the search bar is appearing correctly at the top of the table. I can type into the search bar, but the results are not filtering. How do I implement filtering? What needs to go into the updateSearchResultsForSearchController function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your data source (`campgrounds`) using the text entered into the search bar (`searchController.searchBar.text`), and then reload your table view with the filtered data.

If you want to keep your data source as a computed property, you'll need to define a new variable to hold an array of the filtered campgrounds (see below).  You'll then have to introduce checks to determine which data source to use depending on whether the search controller is active or not.

Alternatively, you could use a single data source, which returns an array of filtered or unfiltered campgrounds as necessary.

Note that you need to `import Foundation` to use `rangeOfString()`.

Try something along the following lines:

```
import Foundation

/* ... */

var filtered: [Campground]?

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {        
    filtered = campgrounds?.filter {
        // True if facilityName contains search bar text (case-sensitive).
        $0.facilityName.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text!) != nil
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

/* ... */

extension SearchCampgroundsViewController: UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.active && !searchController.searchBar.text.isEmpty {
            return filtered?.count ?? 0
        }

        return campgrounds?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("campgroundCell")! as UITableViewCell

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered?[indexPath.row].facilityName ?? "NO NAME FOR THIS FACILITY"
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = campgrounds?[indexPath.row].facilityName ?? "NO NAME FOR THIS FACILITY"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented this code. It is filtering, though not very accurately. For example, if I type a "D" it still displays the items at the top of that list that begin with A. Also, when I click into the search bar, the list disappears. What part of the code controls this?

Comment: Re accuracy—the filter criterion used in the example code is whether the facilityName contains the search text, not whether the facilityName starts with the search text.  If you prefer the latter, you can replace `rangeOfString()` with `hasPrefix()`.

Comment: Re disappearing list—This is probably controlled by the parts of the example code that check `self.searchController.active` (which is true as soon as you tap on the search bar).  I’ve edited those parts to add a check to make sure the search bar text is not empty.  That should prevent the original list of campgrounds from disappearing until some text has been entered into the search bar.